# How can I fix a 7 Days To Die A21 vehicle modding error?

Tags: modding

I am trying to make a mod in 7 Days To Die A21 that adds in vehicles, and I have hit a bit of a snag. Whenever the vehicle gets spawned in, it throws a ton of red text.

The error reads "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

When I check the actual log file, it says:

```
    NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at EntityVehicle.Init (System.Int32 _entityClass) [0x00070] in <d7dcfa4979674f179c13273f8b30b551>:0 
  at EntityDriveable.Init (System.Int32 _entityClass) [0x00000] in <d7dcfa4979674f179c13273f8b30b551>:0 
  at EntityFactory.CreateEntity (EntityCreationData _ecd) [0x004c2] in <d7dcfa4979674f179c13273f8b30b551>:0 
  at EntityFactory.CreateEntity (System.Int32 _et, System.Int32 _id, ItemValue _itemValue, System.Int32 _count, UnityEngine.Vector3 _transformPos, UnityEngine.Vector3 _transformRot, System.Single _lifetime, System.Int32 _playerId, System.String _skinName, System.Int32 _spawnById, System.String _spawnByName) [0x0001b] in <d7dcfa4979674f179c13273f8b30b551>:0 
  at EntityFactory.CreateEntity (System.Int32 _et, System.Int32 _id, UnityEngine.Vector3 _transformPos, UnityEngine.Vector3 _rotation) [0x0000c] in <d7dcfa4979674f179c13273f8b30b551>:0 
  at EntityFactory.CreateEntity (System.Int32 _et, UnityEngine.Vector3 _transformPos, UnityEngine.Vector3 _rotation) [0x00000] in <d7dcfa4979674f179c13273f8b30b551>:0 
  at ItemActionSpawnVehicle.ExecuteAction (ItemActionData _actionData, System.Boolean _bReleased) [0x0016f] in <d7dcfa4979674f179c13273f8b30b551>:0 
  at ItemClass.ExecuteAction (System.Int32 _actionIdx, ItemInventoryData _data, System.Boolean _bReleased, PlayerActionsLocal _playerActions) [0x0055b] in <d7dcfa4979674f179c13273f8b30b551>:0 
  at Inventory.Execute (System.Int32 _actionIdx, System.Boolean _bReleased, PlayerActionsLocal _playerActions) [0x00037] in <d7dcfa4979674f179c13273f8b30b551>:0 
  at PlayerMoveController.Update () [0x026b0] in <d7dcfa4979674f179c13273f8b30b551>:0 

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at EntityVehicle.CheckForOutOfWorld () [0x00171] in <d7dcfa4979674f179c13273f8b30b551>:0 
  at EntityVehicle.PhysicsFixedUpdate () [0x0032a] in <d7dcfa4979674f179c13273f8b30b551>:0 
  at EntityVehicle.FixedUpdate () [0x00000] in <d7dcfa4979674f179c13273f8b30b551>:0
```

And it eventually repeats.

I have tried built in game models, it threw the same error, even when I copy the actual XML code of the vehicle over to mine. I used someone else's model temporary, and it kept doing it again. When I copied that same person's model, code, and inserted it all directly into my mod, without modifying any part of it, it ran, but now I want to actually use my model, sounds, code, and it's being stubborn.

I set up my prefab for the vehicle exactly how it was done here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qlX15Kste0, but the issue still persists. I feel like I am overlooking an very important detail, but I'm not sure what it is.

Edit: I fixed the previous error. Now I think it's a physics error because it just flies. How do I fix this?

Comment: If the NullPointer Error is not there anymore, edit your question to only contain information for the new bug. Because right now, only the first sentence and the last two are actual needed information. You might add a bit more information about how you set up your car if you think it is a physics error

Comment: If you solved the problem, but have a new one, please post the new problem as a new separate question (and ideally also provide an answer to the original question explaining how you solved that problem).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by changing:

```
<property class="chassis">
    <property name="class" value="Chassis"/>
    <property name="display_name" value="chassis"/>
    <property name="slot_type" value="chassis"/>
    <property name="mesh" value="Body"/>
    <property name="transform" value="Mesh/Body"/>
    <property name="paint" value="Body"/>
</property>
```

to:

```
<property class="chassis">
    <property name="class" value="Chassis"/>
    <property name="display_name" value="chassis"/>
    <property name="slot_type" value="chassis"/>
    <property name="mesh" value="m26pershingeagle7"/>
    <property name="transform" value="Mesh/car_mesh/m26pershingeagle7"/>
    <property name="paint" value="m26pershingeagle7"/>
</property>
```